# What's the max number of accountSubscribes recommended?

Tags: rpc

I would imagine that it would be unwise to subscribe to too many account with `accountSubscribe`.

Putting dropped messages aside: is there a recommended limit for an given IP + RPC node, or is the marginal cost low enough to subscribe to many many accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator itself accepts a [`--rpc-pubsub-max-active-subscriptions`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/6684c62280d824a03e789f0e100a78c634bb1f01/validator/src/main.rs#L1409-L1418) configuration flag, whose default is set [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/3f4731b37ff54a444d378a1ee7049cce1f0d4f75/rpc/src/rpc_pubsub_service.rs#L28).

Each RPC may impose their own limits; you will have to contact your RPC provider and ask.